# C++ Checking to see if a variable stored in a vector list contains a character of another variable of another list

Tags: c++, list, file, vector, counter

Im currently writing a program which main function is to read files and perform calculations. Currently im working on a function whos function is to process a set of calcuations based on variables within multiple text files. Below are two text files needed for this function

Customers.txt

```
Carly:Cat:ABCCCCE.
Dodgy Dan:Dog:BCACECC.
Ernie:Ettin:AABCCDD.
Sally:Snake:AEEEEEE.
```

Parts.txt

```
A:Head:1:2:15.
B:Torso:0:6:5.
C:Leg:0:4:6.
D:Arm:0:4:8.
E:Tail:0:6:2.
```

The main function of robotComplexity() is too take in two vectors, one for parts and one for customer, and comparing a variable from each(partCode and listofParts). If char partCode can be found within string listofParts, then this is added to a counter++. The reason for this is due to the variable complexity found in Parts. If part code is equal to A(partCode)then the complexity is 15, if its Equal to B then the complexity is 5. listofParts contains a random assortment of these characters and once the sum of all the complexities is calculated then the function can use the int values attached to this characters to perfrom calcuations. My problem with my attempt is that when it runs a number 65656565656565656565656565656565656565656566666666666666666666666666666666667676767676767676767676767676767676767676767676786868686868686868686868686868686868686969696969696969696969696969696 is returned in the console as the total. An actual expected output is shown below. The function is question can be found near the end of the code provided.

Main code

```
int main()
{
    auto parts =  readpartFile();
    auto newVec = readcustomerFile();
    robotComplexity(parts,newVec);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

```
std::stringstream partsList(
    R"(A:Head:1:2:15.
B:Torso:0:6:5.
C:Leg:0:4:6.
D:Arm:0:4:8.
E:Tail:0:6:2.)");

std::stringstream customerList(
    R"(A:Head:1:2:15.
B:Torso:0:6:5.
C:Leg:0:4:6.
D:Arm:0:4:8.
E:Tail:0:6:2.)");

double robotComplexity(std::vector<Part> const& parts,std::vector<Customer> const& customers)
{
    double Robotcomplexity;
    vector<Part> part = parts;
    vector<Customer> customer = customers;
    int total = 0;

for(Part par: parts) {

for (Customer cus :customers)
{
for (int i = 0; i < cus.listofParts.size(); i++) {

    if(cus.listofParts.find(par.partCode) != string::npos) {
    total =+ par.partCode;
      cout << cus.customerName << " robot contains parts. " << cus.listofParts << "The sum of complexities equals " << total;
    }

}
}
}
return Robotcomplexity;
}
```

an example output of this function would be

```
"Dodgy Dans robot contains parts BCACECC. The sum of complexities equals 46"
```

46 comes from the complexitys found in ABCDE. The complexity for B is 5, for C is 6, for A is 15 and for E is 2. These values are sumed up according to how many times they appear to reach a number 46.

My quesiton would be how can i check if a variable listofParts contains the characters of partCode(ABCDE) and if it does, count them. After this the cooresponding values of complexity for each instance of partCode can be used for a calculation shown above.

if any further explanation is required feel free to ask. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: it is not clear what is your question

Comment: Please read last paragraph.

Comment: you want to check if a string contains characters from a second string and count them? If that is the case, it doesnt really matter if those strings are inside a vector.

Comment: there seems to be lots of not relevant stuff in the question. I cannot really tell it apart, but for example reading from a file seems not to be the problem so you could remove it. Please read about [mcve]. Splitting something big into small chuncks is an important skill to reduce complexity

Comment: It seems to me like this wall of text boils down to "how do I count the occurrences of a given character in a string", which is `std::count(thestring.begin(), thestring.end(), thecharacter)`.

Comment: @idclev463035818 i ensure you everything here is needed. This is half the code of this program, all code shown is needed to sure my issue and why its occuring.

Comment: @molbdnilo can this be used between two different variables of two different vectors?

Comment: @idclev463035818 ive removed these functions if that makes it eaiser. Ive simply been told by other users to include all code that causes the issue so that people can run it for themselves.

Comment: @idclev463035818 this requires the use of my readfile functions

Comment: @idclev463035818 ive added streams eqqual to the contents of the file.

Comment: the acutal question got a bit lost during this discussions. I'll delete all my comments. please clarify if all you want to do is counting how many characters in one string appear in a second string

Comment: @DavidLing  The files are irrelevant, and so are the struct members that you don't use.

Comment: @molbdnilo i believe there is enough code now to see my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boiling down your example to the essentials:

```
struct Customer {
    std::string listofParts;
};

struct Part {
    char partCode;
    int complexity;
};

float complexity(const Customer& c, const std::vector<Part>& parts)
{
    float total = 0;
    for (const auto& p: parts)
    {
        total += std::count(c.listofParts.begin(), c.listofParts.end(), p.partCode) 
                 * p.complexity;
    }
    return total;
}

void robotComplexity(const std::vector<Part>& parts, const std::vector<Customer>& customers)
{
    for (const auto& cus :customers)
    { 
          cout << cus.customerName 
               << " robot contains parts. " 
               << cus.listofParts 
               << "The sum of complexities equals " << complexity(cus, parts);
    }
}
```

Comment: okay thankyou. sorry for the confusing question. May i ask one thing. What value would get parsed into complexity for the parameter const Customer& c? I understand its a reference variable. I have created a variable Customer x in my main but am unsure what value id assign to it

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. It's passed from `robotComplexity`, which gets its vector of `Customer`s from the mysteriously named `newVec` in  `main`.

Comment: Yup i figured it out. Im also wondering, when it runs it only returns the first letter of each persons name but i cant seem to find any code here that would do so.

Comment: That's possible because `readcustomerFile` only stores the first letter. Have you looked at your `Customer`s and determined that they are what you expect?

Comment: ah yes. When i copied over the readpartFile function i left the index of 0 for the first token. Thankyou for your help.